# CMake ExternalProject_Add proxy settings

Tags: proxy, cmake

I have been quite successfully using CMake to perform builds using the `ExternalProject_Add` function, but my company recently put in a proxy server... Which has broken the aforementioned build scripts.

The download step fails during the extract phase because the tarball that was downloaded is only the redirect request from the proxy server (at least I think this is what is contained in the tiny tarball it acquires).

I found this [post](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-May/029533.html) on the CMake mailing-list. I thought maybe if it worked for the `file()` command it might work for the `ExternalProject_Add()` command. I set both `http_proxy` and `HTTP_PROXY` environment variables, but still received the same error. I have thought about overriding the `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND` argument with a `wget` call since this command seems to behave with the proxy settings. However, I wanted to know if there was a better way.

**UPDATE 1:** I checked the contents of the small tarball, and it does contain HTML; however, it is a notification that Authentication is required. I'm not sure why it is requiring authentication because I haven't had to enter any login information for `wget`.
 `wget` shows the following output:

```
Resolving webproxy... 10.0.1.50 
Connecting to webproxy|10.0.1.50|:80... connected. 
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Download begins here...
```

**UPDATE 2:** I have also noticed that both `apt-get` and `svn` fail with this new proxy setup, but `git` does not... `svn` complains about "Server sent unexpected return value (307 Proxy Redirect)..." Very confusing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of CMake are you using? The file(DOWNLOAD command started using the follow redirect flag in version 2.8.2, introduced by the following commit:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=ef491f78218e255339278656bf6dc26073fef264

Using a custom DOWNLOAD_COMMAND is certainly a reasonable workaround.

Comment: I am using CMake 2.8.5; I will definitely give `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` a try!

Comment: I tried `export CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=1`, but I get the same error. Is this how you're supposed to set it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set anything, it should just automatically follow redirects. Prior to that commit, it didn't.

Comment: It turned out to be overly zealous network admins were the problem :) So, I'll accept your post anyway :D

Comment: "You can't be too careful these days." - A network admin, somewhere. :-)